# Gathering data from text file lines in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the values from a .txt file. Like for example:

**Answer from 127.0.0.1 tries=1 Time=1s id=1**

**Answer from 127.0.0.1 tries=1 Time=2s id=1**

**Answer from 127.0.0.1 tries=1 Time=15s id=1**

**Answer from 127.0.0.1 tries=1 Time=12s id=1**

**Answer from 127.0.0.1 tries=1 Time=4s id=1**

I want to accumulate all the "Time=xs" word from each of these lines and save them into a variable (list, array etc) if possible. I can already access the .txt file and have tried splitting it to get the lines separately, but i cannot seem to have them as a result.

```
with open("file.txt", "rt") as file:                
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines: 
        time = line.split(" ")
```

I am still a beginner so please excuse me if this problem is trivial.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to use `readlines()` here, you can iterate over file: `for line in file`. To extract time form each line you can apply [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (*regular expressions*) . `match = re.search('Time=(\d+)s', line) ; if match: time = match.group(1)`. Also you could get index of `'Time'` using `str.find()` and using same function get index of first `'s'` after: `idx = line.find('Time') ; if idx >= 0: time = line[idx + 5: line.find('s', idx + 5)]`. To convert `str` to `int` you can use [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expression

```py
import re

with open("file.txt") as f:
    times = re.findall(r"Time=(\d+)s", f.read())
    print(times)

# ['1', '2', '15', '12', '4']
```

Note: `f.read()` reads entire file contents into memory. So if the file is huge you should iterate over the file object and apply the pattern using `re.search()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty list and store the 4th element of the split line

```
times = []
with open("file.txt", "rt") as file:                
    for line in file: 
        times.append(line.split(" ")[4])
```

Comment: You can avoid `file.readlines()` and simply do `for line in file`

Comment: This will produce a list of the form `["Time=1s", "Time=2s", ...]`

Comment: Small "hack", you can extract time using `line.split(" ")[4][5:-1]`.

Comment: OP has mentioned that he wants to accumulate Time=xs